# Session Beans for Entity Classes in Netbeans 7.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm using **Netbeans 7.2** . Can any one tell how to create **Session Beans for Entity Classes**. Because there is no option called Session Beans for Entity Classes in netbeans version 7.2

(I already created the **Entity Classes** from the **database** and Im using **JBoss eap 5.1** )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project (whether Web project or EJB) -> New -> Other -> Persistence -> Session Beans for Entity Classes. See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Actually I want to add session beans for Entity Classes for Web Project not a EJB one

Comment: Check this http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/netbeans-ecommerce-tutorial.html?print=yes

(find **Adding Entity Classes** topic)

Comment: @yapa I've checked and first two steps of Adding Session Beans subsection are exactly what I've suggested, you get the same dialogue. That's what you asked - how to create Session Beans for Entity Classes with already created Entity classes, right?

Comment: I figured out that thing. We need to use JavaEE6 to use **Session Beans for Entity Classes**. But i'm using JavaEE5. That was the issue. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

There is such an options. However, have you installed Netbeans with JavaEE support?

Maybe your project lacks the right setup for Netbeans to provide this option. Try to create a new WebProject and check if it works there.

Comment: But i can create Entity Classes from the database know. its mean that I have installed Netbeans with JavaEE support know. Am I right.

Comment: Could be. Have you checked New | Other | Enterprise JavaBeans?